# how to make an attached EBS volume accessible?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, mount, amazon-ebs

I changed my instance type, and now previously attached volumes are not available at startup. How do I attach and mount volumes?

In the volume info in the AWS console:

```
Attachment information i-e85c62d0 (hongse):/dev/sdf (attached)
```

however there is nothing at `/dev/sdf` on the instance.

I tried to mount it [following the info](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-using-volumes.html) on the AWS site such as:

```
ubuntu@hongse:~$ sudo mkdir /ebs1
ubuntu@hongse:~$ sudo mount /dev/sdf /ebs1
mount: special device /dev/sdf does not exist
```

but failed.

What other steps could I try to mount an existing volume?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, you're using ubuntu in AWS with an ECS volume. Try this:

```
ubuntu@hostname1:~$ lsblk
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvda    202:0    0   128G  0 disk 
└─xvda1 202:1    0   128G  0 part /
xvdf    202:80   0  1000G  0 disk
```

Note that xvdf (1TB) drive is not mounted in my example.
You will want to type the following to mount your disk:

```
ubuntu@hostname1:~$ sudo mount /dev/xvdf /ebs1
```

NOTE: I don't know the reason why the AWS console shows /dev/sdf and the actual host shows /dev/xvdf, but that's the way it is.

Comment: exactly, that did it! their actual docs used `xvdf` and that worked. thanks so much! you just have to know where the typos are and its a walk in the park!